# Graphie : « f » ou « ph » ?

Tags: étymologie, orthographe, grec

Je sais que certains préfixes comme *philo-*, *physio-*, *phon(é-o)-*, et certains suffixes comme *-graphe*, *-graphie*, *-sphère*, *-phone* (par exemple) s'écrivent avec *ph* et pas *f*.

Cependant quelles sont les règles qui dictent la graphie des mots tels que :

> dauphin (et pas daufin) et nénuphar (et pas nénufar)

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pour approfondir la réponse de user17348, le phonème /f/ fait appel en grec à la lettre Phi Φ qui, on le voit dans son nom, est écrit ph- dans sa forme latinisée ; il utilise en revanche en latin la lettre F. Ainsi, F et PH forment tous deux le son /f/ mais les mots latins « natifs » utilisent la lettre F tandis que les mots grecs ou importés du grec utilisent le digraphe PH, ce qui permet de distinguer leur origine.

Il n'existe toutefois pas de « règle » permettant de savoir lequel utiliser si l'on ne connaît pas le mot au préalable.

Answer (score 3):

Les mots d'origine grecque s'écrivent avec un -ph

Dauphin vient ainsi du latin "delphinus", qui est lui-même un emprunt au grec

Nénufar s'écrit indifféremment avec un -f ou un -ph, mais vu qu'il s'agit d'un mot arabe le -f est plus logique. Toutefois la graphie -ph, apparue en 1935 pour rapprocher la graphie du mot de "nymphéa" reste courante.